understanding fisheries model output tag and release
I am reviewing (for myself) a publication that has analysed data from an experiment to see what effect underwater seismic has on catchability of lobsters. de Lestang et al (2024) Fisheries Research Vol 277: 107072
I am looking for guidance on how best to interpret the results because I am not convinced the conclusions are as definitive as discussed.
Here are the model details as described in the paper;
A total of 190 lobster, 96 and 94 from the treatment and control groups, respectively, were released alive back into the ocean
The return of lobsters from each group (treatment or control) was modelled based on a modified Baranov catch equation (Quinn and Deriso, 1999);
$R_{i,g} = (N_{i,g}^ {}-F_{i-1,g})q_{i}e^{(-l_{i}(C+M)+T)}$
where the number of lobsters recaptured and reported (R) on the ith observation varied based on the number of lobsters released (N) of that group (g, either treatment or control), the cumulative harvest of lobster (retained by fisher; F), after time since release (l in days), that observation’s catchability (q), pre-determined daily natural mortality + tag loss (M) and two factors that acted only on treatment lobster group; instantaneous initial release mortality (T) and instantaneous chronic mortality (C). The rates of natural mortality and chronic tag loss were combined into a single value for use in the model as a daily instantaneous rate (6.643e⁻⁴ per day) based on previous tag-recapture studies on this species (de Lestang et al., 2022). The catchability of both groups of lobster was considered to be the same but could change between sampling occasions (i) based on the number of pots set in that area and daily environmental conditions such as water temperature and ocean swell (de Lestang et al., 2009; Srisurichan et al., 2005). Catchability was a scaling factor in the model calculated so the sum of estimated recaptures for a sampling occasion matched the sum of observed recaptures for that same occasion. Initial release mortality was applied only once to treatment lobsters and represented the “medium-term impact” of the airgun sound wave on lobster survival. Recaptured and re-released lobsters did not have initial release mortality re-applied. Chronic mortality was applied as a consistent monthly impact that continued to reduce the recapture of the released treatment lobsters (longer-term impact). Model estimates of
instantaneous seismic-induced mortality (e.g., T and C) were back transformed from an instantaneous rate by the equation:
$\alpha = 1-e^{-\alpha }$  where α represents either T or C.
The observed data was tested for overdispersion using the “dis-persiontest” function in the AER package (Kleiber and Zeileis, 2008), which determined that a log-likelihood assuming a Poisson distribution (dpois function in R) was appropriate. The negative of this log-likelihood was minimised using the “nlminb” routine in R studio to adjust the estimated model parameters of initial release and chronic mortalities (Table 2). Confidence limits around model estimates were constructed using a Montecarlo approach of 10000 multivariate normal distribution random draws based on model covariate and covariance matrix estimates (using the “rmvnorm” function in the mvtnorm package in R).
The estimated Instantaneous Mortality rate was
median = 0.221, lower 95%CI = .056, upper 95% CI = 0.686
Question: Should this estimate be considered unstable given the very large range of the CI?
Here is a graphic I am trying to make sense of.
Question: Why are the error bars asymmetric in opposite directions for control(purple) versus treatment (yellow) - Figure a
Question: Is the correct interpretation of the residuals - Figure b  - that there is much less compatability between the observed and modelled data during the initial recaptures however it gets better over time but this is expected given the very small recaptures as time went by.

